# Regex: Finding number before and after

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regex and am stuck, so need help to get the id 13 through regex please, thank you :)

```
$str = 'How many points would you like to add or subtract?
(Note: Key a negative number to deduct points)

The following user will be updated:

ID: 13
Name: Alex
Company: Unknown
Current Points: 2';

$id = preg_match_all('/ID: (\d+)/', $str); 
print_r($id); // 1
```

Hoping to find a way to match '13' and not '1'

Comment: Just lookbehind for `ID:`? Or am I missing something

Comment: oh thanks for the reply, it helped my understanding

Comment: I rolled the question back. If an answer solved the question, consider accepting it. This marks your question as closed/solved.

Comment: yea I realised haha, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
(?<=ID: )
```

to identify a position which is preceeded by `ID:`, and then match digits with `\d+`:

```
$str = "How many points would you like to add or subtract?
(Note: Key a negative number to deduct points)

The following user will be updated:

ID: 13
Name: Alex
Company: Unknown
Current Points: 2";

preg_match_all('/(?<=ID: )\d+/', $str, $matches);
```

Note that if you're only looking for a single match, you should use `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply! right now I'm only getting 1 tho, and not 13

Comment: It's working for me, I did test it. Are you sure you included the `+` after `\d`? (a `\d` alone will only match a single digit)

Comment: may I ask what you put for $matches?

Comment: Don't define it with anything initially, just use the code in my answer - the `$matches` variable gets populated through the `preg_match_all`. (don't use the *return value* from `preg_match_all`, that returns the number of matches - instead, just use the `$matches` variable)

Comment: oh, thanks! I managed to get it :), ill change my answer above.
Thank you sooo much for the swift replies!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "How many points would you like to add or subtract?
(Note: Key a negative number to deduct points)

The following user will be updated:

ID: 13
Name: Alex
Company: Unknown
Current Points: 2";

preg_match("#ID: (?<id>\d+)#", $s, $matches);
print_r($matches['id']); // output: 13
```

Comment: hey! thanks for the reply, appreciate it, I've found a solution Yeap

Answer (score 0):

Try with `non-captureing` group for ID and `capturing` group for digits like `$re = '/(?:ID: )(\d+)/m';`. See [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/IptNf0/2)

```
<?php 
$re = '/(?:ID: )(\d+)/m';
$str = 'How many points would you like to add or subtract?
(Note: Key a negative number to deduct points)

The following user will be updated:

ID: 13
Name: Alex
Company: Unknown
Current Points: 2';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
echo $matches[0][1];
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/bChBi